# How to make a video shareable on Instagram and Tiktok from a web app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, social-media, tiktok, tiktok-api

I have an idea for a business that makes custom videos for people through a web app. The hope is that people will want to share these videos on social media and my business will go viral. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make it easy to share on Instagram and TikTok, something like the share button you'd find in an app, which opens a menu to select which app you'd like to share on.

Is this possible from a webapp? Is there a link I can send the user to that will tell Instagram/TikTok the URL of the video they want to share? Or an API I can use? Thanks

Comment: That's 2 different questions, since the APIs if they exist will be different and the code for each will differ.  Have you searched for APIs for either?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaveS I'm not asking for someone to literally give me the code. I'm asking about the general approach. The API docs I've seen seem to focus on managing your own account, not allowing a user to post to their account.

Comment: It's still two different APIs, so one might be yes, one might be no, one is done with X, one is done with Y, and it seems (to me) better to ask two different questions not one.  Just my opinion of course, I'm not a mod.